# Appropriate sections in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am new to Lyx and I want to know, how one can set appropriate sections in there. I hope this is the real term but if you don't know what I am saying here is a picture of it.

[image]

Comment: Do zou mean breaks between paragraphs?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes. When I type enter I get some weird indention.

Comment: That is the default of LaTeX. I bet there is a menu hidden in LyX, but i am not a LzX user. In the meantime, you can add package `parskip` to your preamble.

Comment: Your Wikipedia Snippet is in german, for some detail: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/113/wie-erhalte-ich-eine-leerzeile-zwischen-absatzen

Comment: @Johannes_B Danke ;)

Comment: Perhaps the following is useful? Document > Settings > Text Layout. Look at "paragraph separation". You can choose "indentation" or "vertical space".

Comment: @scottkosty Thank you very much, that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Document > Settings > Text Layout. Look at "paragraph separation". You can choose "vertical space".

Comment: Just upgrading mz system. Seems it is time to install LyX to do some support ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B indeed :) Actually that would be a big help. I think the ratio of {questions about lyx} to {unique number of people answering questions about lyx} is pretty high so it would be nice to get more help.

Comment: Thought so quite a lot over at LaTex-community. I am pretty much alone there.